# Focus Function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, focus

This function changes the background color of the text box to red when it is clicked on. I was wondering how do I make it return to its original color when it isn't being clicked on?

```
$('#textfield').focus(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `blur`, `addClass()`, and `removeClass()` for this:

```js
$('#textfield').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
}); 
$('#textfield').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input tpye="text" id="textfield" value=""/>
```

Comment: @user3557489 glad it helped, don't forget to mark the question solved : )